# How do I add custom Groovy to steps or conditionalSteps?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

Using job-dsl I can execute a Shell script with custom bash code and have the process result influence the status (failure, success etc.) of the Jenkins job:

```
 steps {
    shell('./smoketest.sh')
 }
```

What if I want to use custom Groovy to do a smoketest rather than rely on a shell script? I tried writing a simply Groovy function to return 0 or -1 to signal success and failure, but it does not work. How can I execute arbitrary Groovy code in a step?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `groovyCommand` or `groovyScriptFile` steps to execute any Groovy code as build step. These steps are provided by the [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin). See the plugin documentation for details.

See the Job DSL API viewer for details about the DSL syntax:

- https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-steps-groovyCommand
- https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-steps-groovyScriptFile

Example:

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    groovyCommand('println "Hello"') {
      groovyInstallation('groovy-2.4.2')
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the Groovy script will run on the build agent. So it needs a Java and a Groovy installation.

If you want to run the scripts on Jenkins master (not recommended, it's a bottleneck), use the `systemGroovyCommand` or `systemGroovyScriptFile` steps.

Answer (score -1):

```
@NonCPS
def myFunction(x) {
    if(x)return true
    return false
}

node{
    if(myFunction('')){
        echo 'OK'
    }else{
        error 'error message'
    }
}
```